# The Equation of a buckled card

Tags: statics

When a rectangular piece of plastic (say a credit card) experiences an increasing compression force, the plastic eventually buckles. Is it possible to find the equation of the plastic's cross section once it has buckled elastically?

What I have in mind is two fingers squeezing a plastic card. The fingers are $x$ cm apart, and the card itself has dimensions $l\times b$ cm and negligible thickness. Suppose $x \leq l$ (so that the card is compressed in a direction parallel to its original length $l$. Can we find an equation for the card's deflection $y$ in terms of $x,h,b$ and (I guess) the elastic modulus?

[image]

Does the [Euler column buckling result](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiMoMTj4ePHAhXEN6YKHd5kAuQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.aeromech.usyd.edu.au%2FAMME2301%2FDocuments%2FChapter09.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE9E-ZyR6-WqQ7N_CkzOeYt6hDNJw&sig2=aLYWveV2N_tMTB0Fyl9ulQ) work here? That is, can we expect a solution of the form $y=A\sin(\pi z/x)$? If yes, for small deflections is it safe to assume that the arc length of the curve is equal to $l$?

I'm nervous about using this, because I'm assuming negligible thickness. Do I have to allow the card to have non-zero thickness? Can I then use this to find the value of $A$?

Comment: Are you saying that the card has dimensions $b$x$h$ and you are squeezing the card along $b$? Or are you somehow compressing only a portion of the card's length? Also, in elastic buckling the cross-sections remain perpendicular to the centroidal axis, so the cross-section is not modified. Do you mean to ask for the equation of deflection at buckling?

Comment: I have questions along the lines of @Wasabi. The deflected shape is smooth, so it is described by the end conditions and the deflection at any point. The only question is the number of times that the shape crosses zero between the ends. Or are we missing something? A sketch would help a lot!

Comment: @Wasabi, I've tried to clarify the question. The cross-section is not modified.

Comment: @hazzey, I'm pretty much only interested in the "first mode" of the solution - so no zeros between the ends. I've tried editing the question to clarify.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you mean by "assuming negligible thickness". If you consider $t=0$, you're going to get null areas and inertias. You absolutely must consider the card's thickness. Also, "small deflections" makes no sense in buckling. Once the card buckles, the deflections are arbitrarily large. This is what the $A$ represents in the Euler equation. It can be whatever you want, it has no actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axial compression of the member should be negligible compared to the sideways deflection. This means that it doesn't depend on the cross section of the card. This is *exactly* Euler buckling.

The equations for buckling are usually used to determine the load at which buckling will occur. This is where the cross section matters. Once buckling happens, the shape is only defined by the deflection. The length along the member doesn't change (appreciably).

All of this changes once enough force is applied to move into plastic behavior and hinges form.